# How to configure Auditd to see directory name change?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, auditd

In my `/etc/audit/audit.rules`, I have the following watch:

```
-w /some/place/special -p rwxa -k my_key
```

On my filesystem, I have the following tree:

```
/some/place/special/foo/test-rename/james/sub-subdirectory1/a_file
```

...but no event is showing up in the log when I run:

```
mv /some/place/special/foo/test-rename/james/sub-subdirectory1/a_file /some/place/special/foo/test-rename/bill/sub-subdirectory1/a_file
```

How do I configure `auditd` to catch this?

Answer (score 1):

If a subdirectory is a mountpoint, it will be skipped.  Use '-q' to disable this behavior.

Also, verify that the rule loaded properly by running:

```
auditctl -l
```

to list all rules.

It is also advisable to use syscall rules (e.g., '-a') instead of watch rules ('-w') since the syscall rules are more versatile.  The equivalent syscall rule for your rule is:

```
-a always,exit -F path=/some/place/special -F perm=rwxa
```

If the file movement is still not getting audited, I suggest, try some other operation, e.g., creating a file or a directory in the 'special' directory, since that will trigger the 'w' permission.

It is always a good idea to use some other operation with 'strace' to identify which syscalls are getting used.